# How to display data from angular service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, service, controller

I am having trouble with displaying data from a service to my html view using angularJS.  I am trying to display a list of submitted forms called Occurrences in my view. I then want to be able to click on the list item and view the all data fields that was submitted through the form. The following is my code:

service.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.occurences')
    .service('occcurencesService', occcurences);

occcurences.$inject = ['$http', '$log', '$q', 'configuration','service_helpers'];

function occcurences($http, $log, $q, configuration, service_helpers) {
    this.selectAll = selectAll;
    this.select = select;
    this.insert = insert;
    this.delete = deleteOccurence;
    this.update = update;

    var baseUrl = configuration.redSkyServiceBaseUrl;
    var occurencesUrl = baseUrl + 'api/occurences';

    // var deferred = $q.defer();
    var occurencesData = {};

    $http.get(occurencesUrl)

    function select(id) {

        $log.log("Getting occurence " + id);
        var url = occurencesUrl + '/' + id;
        return $http.get(url)
        .then(getDataSuccess)
        .catch(getDataFail)
    }

    function selectAll()
    {
        $log.log("Getting occurences");
        return $http.get(occurencesUrl)
        .then(getDataSuccess)
        .catch(getDataFail)
    }

    function insert(occurence)
    {
        $log.log('Inserting occurence');
        if (!validateOccurence(occurence))
        {
            var errorText = 'Tried to insert invalid occurence: ' + JSON.stringify(occurence);
            $log.error(errorText);
            $q.reject(errorText);

        }

        return $http.post(occurencesUrl, occurence)
        .then(getDataSuccess)
        .catch(getDataFail)
    }

    //TODO: Untested
    function deleteOccurence(occurence)
    {
        $log.log('Deleting occurence  occurence');
        var url;
        if (typeof(occurence) === "number")
        {
            $log.log('Deleting occurence  occurence ' + occcurence);

            url=  occcurencesUrl +'/' + occurence
        }
        else if (typeof(occurence) === "object")
        {
            $log.log('Deleting occurence  occurence ' + occcurence.OccurenceID);
            url=  occcurencesUrl +'/' + occurence.OccurenceID;
        }

        return $http.delete(url)
        .then(getDataSuccess)
        .catch(getDataFail)
    }

    //TODO: Untested
    function update(occurence)
    {
        $log.log('updating occurence');
        if (!validateOccurence(occcurence))
        {
            var errorText = 'Tried to insert invalid occurence: ' + JSON.stringify(occurence);
            $log.error(errorText);
            $q.reject(errorText);

        }
        var url=  occcurencesUrl +'/' + occurence.OccurenceID;
        return $http.put(url, occrence)
        .then(getDataSuccess)
        .catch(getDataFail)
    }

    function validateOccurence (occurence)
    {
        // TODO: validate the occurences
        return true;
    }

    function getDataSuccess(response) {
        return service_helpers.getDataSuccess(response);
    }

    function getDataFail(error) {
        return service_helpers.getDataFail(error)
    }        
}
```

})();

controller.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.occurences')
    .controller('EditOccurrenceFormCtrl', EditOccurrenceCtrl);

EditOccurrenceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'occcurencesService','$log'];

function EditOccurrenceCtrl($scope, $http, occcurencesService, $log) {
    $scope.title = 'Editoccurrence';

    activate();



    function selectOccurrence(occcurencesService) {

        var occurrenceList = this;

        this.select() = occurrenceList.list;
    }

    function activate() {



    }
}
})();
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="EditOccurrenceFormCtrl as editOccurrence">

<p ng-repeat="occurrenceList in occurrenceList.list">       

   {{occurrenceList.name}}: {{occurrenceList.age}}</p></div>
```

Comment: What is the error? Do you see anything in the console? What is working, and what is not? What is the actual behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: also don't use the same name for your iterated element and the array in the `ng-repeat = "occurrenceList in occurrenceList.list"`. You could do instead `ng-repeat = "occurrenceItem in occurrenceList.list"` and then use `occurenceItem` inside that element.

Comment: amd what is `this.select() = occurrenceList.list;` supposed to do? you cannot assign a variable to the result of a function, that is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use editOcurrence, because you are using the controllerAs syntax

```
<div ng-controller="EditOccurrenceFormCtrl as editOccurrence">
    <p ng-repeat="occurrenceList in editOccurrence.occurrenceList.list">       
        {{occurrenceList.name}}: {{occurrenceList.age}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's is a lot of wrong code in the controller - what you need is simple -

```
function controller(occurencesService){
   Var vm =this;
    occurencesService.selectAll().then(function(response){
     vm.occurences = response; 
      }


   vm.selectOccurence = function (occurence) {
           vm.selectedOccurence = occurence;
  }
}
```

We have to resolve the selectall promise before we assign the occurences to the scope ( the vm variable )

When you want to select a specific occurence from the list  use the selectOccurence function in the view bind it to an ng-click event .

Good luck